# Append json data into tables

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm new to Jquery and I have this json file look like this.

```
 var json2 = {
        "data": [
                     {
                         "cid": "Movie",
                         "id": "/en/MIB",
                         "topic": "Men In Black",
                         "audience": [
                             {


                                 "userid": "100003914111287",
                                 "Name" : "Sandi Tan",
                                 "information": [
                                     {
                                         "category": "Athlete",
                                         "source": "Didier Drogba"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "Athlete",
                                         "source": "Frank Lampard"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "Professional sports team",
                                         "source": "Chelsea Football Club"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "favorite_teams",
                                         "source": "Chelsea Football Club"
                                     }
                                 ]
                             },
                             {
                                 "userid": "100003914111287",
                                 "Name": "Celia Tio",
                                 "information": [
                                     {
                                         "category": "Athlete",
                                         "source": "Didier Drogba"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "Athlete",
                                         "source": "Frank Lampard"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "Professional sports team",
                                         "source": "Chelsea Football Club"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "favorite_teams",
                                         "source": "Chelsea Football Club"
                                     }
                                 ]
                             }
                         ],
                         "type": "/soccer/football_team"
                     },
                     {


                         "id": "/en/Harry Potter",
                         "topic": "Harry Potter and the goblet of fire",
                         "audience": [
                             {
                                 "userid": "100003914111287",
                                 "Name": "Gibson Tay",

                                 "information": [
                                     {
                                         "category": "Athlete",
                                         "source": "Ryan Giggs"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "Professional sports team",
                                         "source": "Manchester United"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "favorite_teams",
                                         "source": "Manchester United"
                                     }
                                 ],
                                 "userid": "100003921730958"
                             },

                             {
                                 "userid": "100003914111287",
                                 "Name": "James Tan",
                                 "information": [
                                     {
                                         "category": "Athlete",
                                         "source": "Didier Drogba"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "Athlete",
                                         "source": "Frank Lampard"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "Professional sports team",
                                         "source": "Chelsea Football Club"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "favorite_teams",
                                         "source": "Chelsea Football Club"
                                     }
                                 ]
                             }


                         ],
                         "type": "/soccer/football_team"
                     },

                     {
                         "cid": "Movie",
                         "id": "/en/Iron Man",
                         "topic": "Iron Man",
                         "audience": [
                             {
                                 "userid": "100003914111287",
                                 "Name" : "Edmund Tan",
                                 "information": [
                                     {
                                         "category": "Athlete",
                                         "source": "Didier Drogba"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "Athlete",
                                         "source": "Frank Lampard"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "Professional sports team",
                                         "source": "Chelsea Football Club"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "favorite_teams",
                                         "source": "Chelsea Football Club"
                                     }
                                 ]
                             },



                 ],

                         "type": "/soccer/football_team"
                     }
                 ]

    };
```

How can I extract out the information. I wan only the topic name(e.g Men in black) and the person name (e.g "Sandi Tan") and append into a table which looks like this:

```
**Men in Black, Iron man  Harry Potter**
Sandi Tan     Edmund Tan   Gibson Tay
Celia Tio                  James tan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
json2.data[0].topic //to get Men in black
json2.data[0].audience[0].Name // to get Sandi Tan
```

To get all names and topics you can do it like this with a loop

```
for(key in json2.data){
console.log(json2.data[key].topic);
console.log(json2.data[key].audience[0].Name)
}
```

To append to table

```
$('<td> Audience : '+json2.data[0].audience[0].Name+'</td><td>Topic : '+json2.data[0].topic+'</td>').appendTo(tableid);
```

Dynamically add to table

```
var td ="";
for(key in json2.data){
td += "<tr><td>"+json2.data[key].topic+"</td><td>"+json2.data[key].audience[0].Name+"</td></tr>";
}
$(td).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: But how can i append into a table?

Comment: Can i dynamically add into the table? rather than hardcoded by using json2.data[0].audience[0].Name?

Comment: But Anton How can I make it align in the middle and with a border?

Comment: Do you mean aligning the text? style="text-align:center" or what do you want to align?